# Bypass the signed .pkg file from apple gatekeeeper

Tags: macos, security, package

I have built a macOS app. First I was distributing **Unsigned .pkg**. So whenever client try to install it

[image]

for opening the app, the client has to open through the following steps

```
System Preference >> Security and Privacy >> General tab >> Allow app downloaded from section >> click on Open anyway.
```

So he asked me to create the signed .pkg file. So users don't fear opening malicious software.
So with the following steps, I created signed .app and .pkg both.

So basically I follow these steps:

1. First I created the signed .app file using [**Apple Notarization**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution) and I exported my archive.
2. After getting my signed .app file I use [**Packages**](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to create a .pkg file which is actually unsigned .pkg.

So with help of the following [**command**](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/how-to-sign-macos-pkg-files-for-deployment-with-hexnode-mdm/), I create a signed .pkg

```
productsign -sign “Developer ID Installer: Your Apple Account Name (**********)” ~/Desktop/example.pkg ~/Desktop/signed-example.pkg
```

So finally I created my signed .pkg file.

[image]
So before distributing the app I thought of testing. So I uploaded the .pkg file to my google drive and downloaded it. I was trying to do as the user will do like download the .pkg file and open it.

So did I but when I opened it, it again showing the same above pop up when it was unsigned.

I didn't get the point even my signed .pkg file consider as malicious software.

How to remove this pop-up so users can directly install it without fear.

Any suggestions...

Comment: Use command "spctl -a -vv myapp.app" to verify signature. Your app has to be correctly notarized. There is no other way to avoid this popup. pkg doesnt' have notarization signature. That's your current problem

Comment: It's spctl -a -vv -t install my.pkg + https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123856